# Does $f\in L^1$ implies $\log{|f|}\in L^1$?

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

> Does $f\in L^1$ implies $\log{|f|}\in L^1$?

I think it is not since $|\log|f||$ can be arbitrarily big if $|f|$ is arbitrarily small.

But it seems $\log|f|\in L^1$ is true because of the following inequality,

$$\int_X\log|f|d\mu \leq \log\left(\int_X |f|d\mu  \right)$$  if $\mu(X)=1$ due to Jensen's inequality.

I am stuck with it... Thanks in advance for any hint and answers!

Comment: What if $f$ is the zero function?

Comment: Even if you don't allow $f=0$, the problem is you don't have a **lower** bound on $\int_X \log |f|\; d\mu$, which can be arbitrarily negative.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal Right! there was no restriction for $f$ not to be $0$ !Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you said proves this holds for finite measure spaces, so instead consider
$f(x) = \tfrac{1}{x^2}$ defined on $[1,\infty)$. Then $$\|f\|_1 = \int_1^\infty x^{-2}\,dx = \left. x^{-1}\right|_\infty^1 = 1$$ so $f\in L^1[0,\infty)$ but
$$\int_1^\infty |\log f|\,d\mu = \int_1^\infty 2\log x\,d\mu = \infty$$ so $\log f \not\in L^1[0,\infty)$. Zero function works too (see comments) but this is a nontrivial example.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But what if $\mu(X)=1$? Is there still a counter example of nonzero $f$?

Comment: You are right, you'd need $|\log f| = \log f$, or $f \geq 1$.